# I Formatted My Linux Partition, Now I Can’t boot into Windows

Tags: grub2

I had an old linux partition which I hadn’t used for quite some time, and I realized that I didn’t need it anymore. I then decided to format the whole partition and get on with my life. It was all good, until I restarted my PC. Upon restarting I was greeted with this:

“error: no such device: 0119b88c-c450-41d6-9ddf-a4e5140f74fa
error: unknown filesystem.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>”

I am now very frustrated and out of ideas. I tried using my Windows boot USB to use command prompt and try some things though that didn’t work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Windows booting problems are off-topic, especially when you don't have Ubuntu any more.

Comment: "I am now very frustrated and out of ideas." Find out how to restore the windows bootloader. as pilot6 stated: we only handle Ubuntu related issues. When there is no Ubuntu on your system you need to ask that on a platform for (in this case) Windows. That could be our sister site on http://superuser.com/

Comment: Sorry. I thought this would belong here but I guess not.

Comment: Grub rescue means you have grub stage 0 (the MBR) that then passed to later stages that I'm betting you have now deleted.  You need to `bootrec /fixmbr` (or the appropriate command for your version of windows) to make windows own the MBR. It should have been done before you rebooted, but it's a windows command & off-topic here. Enter commands to boot your windows & run the appropriate windows command from there. Booting a windows on thumb-drive can fix this (*from what I've provided adjusting the command for your version of windows*)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some steps you could do:

- Boot into a windows installation media, for example from an USB. So
  insert the USB which have windows installer flashed on it and boot
  the PC up from this USB. You can flash windows on a USB by
  downloading the Media Creation Tool from Microsoft.
- When you have booted from the USB, press Shift + F10 to open CMD.
- Type "Diskpart".
- Type "List vol"
- Select the system volume by typing the system volume number. So if the system volume is 3, type "sel vol 3".
- Type "Assign letter k".
- Type "Exit" to exit diskpart.
- Type "k:" (remember the colon) to enter the directory we just assigned the letter to.
- Type "dir" and you should see a dir called EFI, now type "cd EFI", then type "dir" again.
- You should now see a dir called Ubuntu, now type "rmdir /S ubuntu" or "rmdir ubuntu" to remove ubuntu. Ubuntu should now be removed and windows should load now, but first we will remove the assigned letter.
- Type "diskpart" again, then "list vol", then select the vol which we assigned the letter to, i.e. the system volume, for example "sel vol 3", then type "remove letter k".
- Done, try rebooting, Ubuntu should be gone from boot now.

To check what operating systems you have installed, you can boot into BIOS and see the boot order, if Ubuntu is still there, you have not uninstalled Ubuntu or the above did not work.